# Gaussian: Warning - assumption of classical behavior for rotation may cause significant error

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I am playing around with a prostaglandin molecule (23 heavy atoms) in Gaussian09. My goal is to calculate the vertical ionization potential and electron affinity for the molecule. I already managed to converge the geometry of a neutral molecule (with the invaluable help of @Wildcat and Greg at this forum) using Opt=Tight and Integral(Grid=Ultrafine) as well as Opt(Maxcycle=1000) and SCF(Maxcycle=1000). In the log file I got the long-awaited line "Stationary point found" :) However there are also two warning messages there that make me worry a bit:

**1. Warning -- assumption of classical behavior for rotation may cause significant error**

**2. Warning -- explicit consideration of  37 degrees of freedom as vibrations may cause significant error**

Now, the zero-point energy that I am interested in has been reported as:

> SCF Done:  E(RB3LYP) =  -1004.62842050     A.U. after   14 cycles

However, right below the warning messages I found something like:

> Zero-point correction=                           0.442805
>   (Hartree/Particle)
>
> Sum of electronic and zero-point Energies=          -1004.185615

Now, my specific questions are:

1. Should I worry too much about these warnings if my resultant Ionization Potentials (IP) and Electron Affinities (EA) look reasonable?
2. Should I do my IP and EA calculations taking the Zero-point correction (see above) into account and use the value of -1004.185615 as my "true" zero-point energy?
3. What can I do to eliminate the warning messages mentioned above? I read something about a keyword "freq=HinderedRotor" that could be used in such a case.

I am eager to know how to interpret this whole mess and how to proceed. Thank you for any help you may offer!

Comment: Which basis set are you using? What do you mean by "true"? Maybe you can retain only the electronic contribution

Comment: # freq b3lyp/6-31g(d) geom=connectivity scf(maxcycle=1000) integral(grid=ultrafine)

Comment: Well, I mean "true" as closer to real zero-point energy that I want to assess for IP and EA calculation. Sorry if I cannot make myself clear enough. I am new to the field of computational chemistry.

Comment: Given the inaccuracy of the method, I would go for neglecting the vibrational rotational parts.

Comment: It is ok. I find hard to justify the usage of these contribution to energy if there are few confidente of their accuracy. Most of they will cancel out.

Comment: Dear @user1420303,

Comment: Dear @user1420303. What specifically do you mean by "inaccuracy of the method"? Is my basis a kind of lousy choice? :) I have gone through a few papers in the field of computational chemistry and it looks like people use it quite a bit, don't they? Thanks a lot for guiding me here!

Comment: 1. B3LYP/6-31g(d)  is ok for many applications. Sometimes it returns in large errors but its usage is a reasonable because it provides good balance cost-benefit. Giving the size of your molecule I think that no one will complain.
The basis set is large of small depending from the place you come. I heard people that commonly uses semiempirical methods and "feels"   B3LYP/6-31g(d)  like a very accurate method.  People trying to reach chemical accuracy (using normally 5$\zeta$ basis sets and high correlated wave function based method will perceive it as very inaccurate or unreliable.

Comment: 2. B3LYP is by far the more used method/functional out there. Pople's basis sets are also very used (years ago almost the only one choice).  So,  you are playing safe. But do not expect to obtain very accurate results for energy differences nor hessians. So, if you have additional inaccuracies because of the assumptions for the statistical physical treatment are not well satisfied, then maybe it is better neglet those contributions. Esto hubiese sido más fácil en español.

Comment: Cool @user1420303! It is very encouraging to hear from an expert who you obviously are that I am playing it safe this way. I'll do as you say then and neglect the warning about zero-point energy correction as long as my results seem reasonable enough comparing a bunch of prostaglandin derivatives. Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: De nada! Sorry, I tried to say that I you could use the value SCF Done: E(RB3LYP) = -1004.62842050 instead of  -1004.185615. Maybe the best you can do is compare the electronic energy difference with the zero point energy difference. They should be quite similar. You can improve the accuracy of the calculation, but I doubt that it pay the price. I do not know about the application of your calculation but, I guess that you calculated for an isolated molecule at 0K to represent the behavior in the human body (condensed phase at ~310K). If so it is not reasonable to invert too much in accuracy.

Comment: Dear @user1420303. Now you got me. Forgive my ignorance, but I just used the default settings of GaussView not even thinking much about the temperature set for the calculation. I kid of thought that it was room temperature 298 K... And you say the default is 0K, right? Well, where can I check the temperature in the LOG file? And second, where can I set it in the GJF file? Well, yes I am interested in the biological system, and specifically the human body so ~310K in the lipid membrane. So what do you think, what would be the optimal settings for this kind of calculation?

Comment: 1) Yes, it is at 0K as you are solving searching for the minimum energy state. At higher temperatures excited states become available. The zero point "correction" is the lower energy due to vibrations that the molecule can have (assuming harmonic oscillations for nuclei), so also implies 0K.
2) You can not check, it must be at 0K. Except in the thermodynamic analysis that  is done at 298.15K by default. It is indicated in this part of the output file.
3) I never calculated energies to be used in biological analysis. But I am pretty sure that due to the difficulties above, you can only ...

Comment: expect to get a qualitative behavior. To that end, I suspect that your method reasonable (that is, it should not be necessary the minor corrections by temperature, differences in basis set and even changes in vibrational energy)